# Which service should I choose to convert a website to mobile app?

Tags: mobile-application

I am a newbie at programming. I know one or two things about c++ and I also have some knowledge with html and php but app developing is too hard for me at this stage. I want to create my mobile app and I heard about services which convert websites into mobile apps. Which service is the best one? Also, I heard that free services are really bad. Is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Jamblam. Link: https://www.jamblamapps.eu They have great quality and performance. Also their prices are a huge plus.

Note: They make only Android apps.
2nd Note: Yes, free services aren't a good choice (crashes/not working).

Answer (score 0):

Jamblam Apps (now changed its name to Shibe Apps but the link is the same) is the best provider. BTW I answered such question before. -1 from me. I recommend looking for already answered questions instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Apache Cordova** and it is free, to convert your website to a mobile app for both iOs and Android applications. Check my explanation and steps on my GitHub profile, follow this link https://github.com/tshele/Convert-any-website-to-IOS-and-Android-with-Cordova